# Distorted headphone sound when using Skype for Linux

Tags: sound, skype, headphones

Recently, i installed on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS, Skype for Linux 8.11.0.4.

The problem is when i call someone, his/hers voice is about 40-50% (approximation) distorted. Really annoying. Searched for a solution, but didn't find anything and many seem to have the same problem.

Is there any solution to this? Or maybe a reference to an official Skype thread with discussion or something?

Skype for Linux seems to be relatively new skype edition. Looks likes the windows 10 internal version.

Comment: I have the same problem...but no solution found. Whenever I need to join a call I switch to the web version of skype.

Comment: I am in this boat too. The sound quality is terrible, I can hardly understand the other party. Very hissy or static-y

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This fix worked for me:

```
sudoedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

and insert:

```
default-fragment-size-msec = 5
```

Comment: also useful to restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k`

Comment: I did both steps and nothing fixed.  Furthermore, i recently  installed a suggested update for skype, but again nothing changed...

Comment: I had the same problem. Applying the solution that @Valentas suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching it as:

```
PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=90 skypeforlinux
```

It worked for me.

Source: https://winaero.com/blog/fix-broken-sound-skype-linux-8-x/